# Change contents of sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site where some of the user's actions occur by clicking on links on a sidebar.  What I am not sure how to do is when the user clicks on a link on the sidebar the whole page will reload due to the referencing, and I want only the contents of the sidebar to change and the rest of the page to stay as is.  For example the user profile will be in the sidebar clicking the link to user profile would have to only display everything in the sidebar and the rest of the page should just display whatever it was displaying before.

Excuse the whole text and for not putting any code but it won't make any difference.

Comment: Definitely include some code. It looks like you need to add a handler to the click event and call `preventDefault` and perform some custom logic (ie to update the sidebar UI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is add a click event on those links with javascript. When you click on it it loads a template of another page. For example :

HTML code:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  Welcome
</div>
```

And this Javascript code:

```
$(".sidebar").click(function(event) {
   $('.sidebar').html('');
   $('.sidebar').load('sidebar2.html');
});
```

What this would do for example is when you click on welcome it would remove the content of the sidebar and replace it with the html present in the file sidebar2.html